# Gazebo and transmissions: mechanicalReduction and motorTorqueConstant

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

could anybody explain the **role and effect** of the transmission parameters  mechanicalReduction and/or motorTorqueConstant when using a SimpleTransmission in Gazebo?

While I do understand the words, I did not really find a lot of documentation on how they actually influence simulated joints.

Thanks

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27502/gazebo-and-transmissions:-mechanicalreduction-and-motortorqueconstant/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transmissions transform state from actuator space to joint space (and efforts from joint space to actuator space).  The robot is simulated in joint space, so in simulation, the efforts are immediately transformed back into joint space (and the state is first transformed from joint space), as shown in [this diagram](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism_model).

In simulation, the `mechanicalReduction` and `motorTorqueConstant` are immediately applied and unapplied, so changing them will have no effect on the simulation.  They only change the reported values of the actuators.

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2012-02-13**:
Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer. If I use one of the predefined controllers, e.g. robot_mechanism_controllers/JointPositionController, on which side of the transmission would it apply its effort?

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2012-02-14**:
The controllers apply effort to the joints.

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2012-02-15**:
So the idea behind this, is that there is some interface to the actuator so that actually the effort on the joint side is controlled and not the effort on the actuator side of the transmission? I assume this is, how the PR2 is built...

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2012-02-15**:
The controller commands effort on the the joint, and the transmission translates them into effort on the actuator.